# Pass propertychanged from Model to View when no databinding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, propertychanged

I know this has been discussed a lot but I haven't been able to get this working.

I have a View - ViewModel - Model in WPF.
I need to pass the info that a property in Model has changed. I need the information eventually to be handled in the View.
Note that there is **no databinding** here from the View to ViewModel.

In *ViewModel* I have a collection of model objects:

```
Public Property Items as ObservableCollection(Of Item)
```

The *Model* is:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property Name as String
End Class
```

What I want to do is to run a procedure in a View code-behind (see below)  that is run any time the property "Name" is changed in any of the items in the collection "Items" in ViewModel.

*View*:

```
Private Sub NameWasChanged()
    'do something to UI...
    'Item that was changed must be known here as must the new value for the "Name" property
End Sub
```

UPDATE 1 >>>

In response to your custom class, I tried to convert it into VB.NET (below) but looks there is some problem with overriding the Event in this derived class. Don't know if "Protected Shadows Event PropertyChanged" is the right way to do it. I get item.PropertyChanged saying "PropertyChanged is not an event of T".
Could you help me with this. Otherwise I got the concept/idea.

```
Public Class BaseCollection(Of T)

Inherits ObservableCollection(Of T)
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Protected currentItem As T

Public Sub New(collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
    Me.New()
    For Each item As T In collection
        Add(item)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub New(collection As ObservableCollection(Of T))
    Me.New(TryCast(collection, IEnumerable(Of T)))
End Sub

Public Sub New(ParamArray collection As T())
    Me.New(TryCast(collection, IEnumerable(Of T)))
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub


Public Shadows Sub Add(item As T)
    AddHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Item_PropertyChanged
    MyBase.Add(item)
End Sub

Public Overridable Shadows Sub Add(collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
    For Each item As T In collection
        Add(item)
    Next
End Sub

Public Overridable Shadows Sub Add(ParamArray items As T())
    Add(TryCast(items, IEnumerable(Of T)))
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As T)
    If item IsNot Nothing Then
        AddHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Item_PropertyChanged
        MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub ClearItems()
    For Each item As T In Me
        RemoveHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Item_PropertyChanged
    Next
    MyBase.ClearItems()
End Sub

Public Shadows Function Remove(item As T) As Boolean
    If item Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    End If
    RemoveHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Item_PropertyChanged
    Return MyBase.Remove(item)
End Function

Public Shadows Sub RemoveAt(index As Integer)
    Dim item As T = Me(index)
    If item IsNot Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Item_PropertyChanged
    End If
    MyBase.RemoveAt(index)
End Sub


Private Sub Item_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
    NotifyPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName)
End Sub


#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Members"

Protected Shadows Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler

Protected Overridable Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ParamArray propertyNames As String())
    For Each propertyName As String In propertyNames
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    Next
End Sub

#End Region


End Class
```

Comment: Why don't you just run your procedure in the view model instead of the view and then bind the view model properties to the view as is customary with WPF?

Comment: In this case the (third-party) UI component I am using is not supporting data binding well yet. So my only option now is to run code-behind to change that UI component. I don't think running UI code from ViewModel is a good idea or can you explain your idea more.

Comment: In general in WPF, changing data or reacting to data changes are not classed as UI code. However, if you can't use standard data binding with your third party control, then I take back my suggestion. Instead, I suggest that you use a decent control that enables standard data binding instead.

Comment: In this case it is not possible to find alternative control that supports binding. I think I need to go out of WPF (MVVM) standard here with this unfortunately. It would work for me if I can catch the model's PropertyChanged event in the ViewModel. How to register for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a model class correctly implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, another class can listen for property changes by attaching a handler to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event:

```
YourObject.PropertyChanged += YourObject_PropertyChanged;

...


Private Sub YourObject_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
    If InlineAssignHelper(e.PropertyName, "Name") Then
        ' Do something with the new Name value here
    End If
End Sub
```

---

UPDATE >>>

If you want to monitor the property changes of each item in your `Items` collection property, then you'll need to attach the handler to each item... you could do something like this:

```
For Each item As Item In Items
    item.Propertychanged += Item_PropertyChanged
Next
```

Or as you add them to `Items`:

```
For Each item As Item In OtherCollection
    item.Propertychanged += Item_PropertyChanged
    Items.Add(item)
Next
```

When I need to do this, I extend the `ObservableCollection<T>` class and override the `Add` methods to attach the handlers (and call them from the constructors) and the override the `Remove` methods to remove the handlers.

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

My extended `ObservableCollection<T>` class is far too long to show here, but to start you off, here is some of it... I just hope I haven't removed too much and that it all still works... either way, I think you'll get the idea:

```
public class BaseCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    where T : class, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BaseCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : this()
    {
        foreach (T item in collection) Add(item);
    }

    public BaseCollection(ObservableCollection<T> collection) : this(collection as IEnumerable<T>) { }

    public BaseCollection(params T[] collection) : this(collection as IEnumerable<T>) { }

    public BaseCollection() : base() { }

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
        base.Add(item);
    }

    public virtual void Add(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        foreach (T item in collection) Add(item);
    }

    public virtual void Add(params T[] items)
    {
        Add(items as IEnumerable<T>);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
        }
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (T item in this) item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    public new bool Remove(T item)
    {
        if (item == null) return false;
        item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
        return base.Remove(item);
    }

    public new void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        T item = this[index];
        if (item != null) item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
        base.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    protected override event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

With this, you can just add a `PropertyChanged` handler to the collection:

```
BaseCollection<YourDataType> items = new BaseCollection<YourDataType>();
items.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: Model implements INotifyPropertyChanged yes. If you look at my original post code, how would you write this? What is YourObject in my case?

Comment: Do I need to attach the handler for every item in the Items ObservableCollection? -> whenever new Item is added to collection, the handler is attached and whenever Item is removed the handler is removed?

Comment: Excellent. Would it be possible to show how you extended the ObservableCollection<T> class ?

Comment: Ah, you can delete that `currentItem` entry which performs other functionality in my base collection that I removed for this example.

Comment: I removed the currentItem. I can't get (in your code) the "item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;" work with VB.NET where I writed it as "AddHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf Item_PropertyChanged" -> PropertyChanged is not en event of T. Can you help here.

Comment: I think that you need to declare the `PropertyChanged` event like this: `Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`... I'm not sue about VB really, I just looked [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Comment: Looks like the base class PropertyChanged is Protected?

Comment: Oh sorry, that's my fault. I stripped too much out of the class when I copied it here. I've added the missing part on the end of the class declaration: `where T : class, INotifyPropertyChanged`. This is basically a condition that means that this collection will only take objects that implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Now the compiler will know that the items of the collection *will* have the `PropertyChanged` event and so the error will disappear.